# Cannot cast a List<dictionary<string,object>> to a List<object>?

Tags: c#, generics, casting

val is declared as an object type, and it is assigned a list dictionary .

```
val object type is {System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, object>>}
```

I can cast it back to "List<Dictionary<string,object>>"

```
val as List<Dictionary<string,object>>  is fine , it returns a list of 3 dictionaries , System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, object>>
```

Dictionary<string,object> is an object type, but why cannot I cast it to "List" ?

```
val as List<object> == null S>
```

Comment: Imagine if the compiler would allow you to do this. What would happen if you added a non-dictionary object to the list `(val as List<object>).Add("hello");` You can convert it using covariant interfaces, eg `val as IReadOnlyList<object>` works, as you can't add items via that interface